# Why Facebook SDK 4.0 "You are already authorized" when I request a new permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I using Facebook SDK 4.0 and my scenario is:

- Login user to Facebook with permissions: "public_profile, user_friends, email"
- Authorize dialog appear and click allow.
- After login success I try to request a new permission: "publish_actions".
- Dialog appear with: "You are already authorized"

My implemented code is:

Login:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(DashboardActivity.this,
                Arrays.asList(FacebookUtils.FACEBOOK_READ_PERMISSION));
```

Listener:

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                if (chototProfile != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(chototProfile.getAccountId())) {
                    connectFB(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                }
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(DashboardActivity.this,
                Arrays.asList(FacebookUtils.FACEBOOK_PUBLISH_PERMISSION));//Request new permission.
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                if (chototProfile != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(chototProfile.getAccountId())
                        && AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    connectFB(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.e(error);
            }
        });
```

**Question Why it happen and How I can fix it?**

Comment: I am also facing same problem, any luck solving it?

Comment: @Shailesh the problem seem happen when the Facebook app is not installed in device. If you have Facebook App installed, the request allow permission dialog will show up.

Comment: I want to set publish permission when Facebook app is not installed.

Comment: I would try this with the latest SDK and using one of the sample projects bundled with the SDK. These projects will give you a good idea on how to approach this.